# Netflix Hollow range queries?

Tags: java, netflix-hollow

I have an Test object in my data model that contains two strings corresponding to start and end dates. The value of the start date string is, for example, "2019-10-23T08:12:33.955191013Z"
Is it possible to create a query, using indexes or otherwise, to select the Test objects that contain a date that is between the start and end dates. If this will not work with strings and the dates need to be longs I can use the number of milliseconds since the epoch instead of strings for the dates. It could be done by getting all of the Test objects in a list and creating a stream with a filter to get the Test objects that contain a date that is between the start and end dates, but I am hoping that there is a more efficient or faster approach. Any help or insights or documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is to use prefix indexes, but you'll still need to filter on the "edges".

https://hollow.how/indexing-querying/#prefix-index

So if you leave the dates as ISO-8601 format, and you want to search between date1 and date2, you can take the prefix that they have in common to filter the collection. That at least will give you a subset of the complete collection to filter.

I also advise putting the date as a long as well as a string, and use the long in your comparisons. That will make the > and < comparisons far more efficient because no String objects need to be created.